# How to loop through an API request for different parameters such as changing the month and header

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook, request

I have the following API request that I then clean and sort the data:

```
    Base_URL = "https://api.jao.eu/OWSMP/getauctions?"

headers = {
    "AUTH_API_KEY": "06e690fb-697b-4ab2-9325-4268cbd14502"
}

params = {
    "horizon":"Daily",
    "corridor":"IF1-FR-GB",
    "fromdate":"2021-01-01"
}

data = "results"

r = requests.get(Base_URL, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
j = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
df=df.explode('results')
    df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('results')).add_suffix('_new'))
    df.drop(['ftroption','identification','horizonName','periodToBeSecuredStart','periodToBeSecuredStop','bidGateOpening','bidGateClosure','isBidGateOpen','atcGateOpening','atcGateClosure','marketPeriodStop','disputeSubmissionGateOpening','disputeSubmissionGateClosure','disputeProcessGateOpening','disputeProcessGateClosure','ltResaleGateOpening','ltResaleGateClosure','maintenances','xnRule','winningParties','operationalMessage','products','lastDataUpdate','cancelled','comment_new','corridorCode_new','productIdentification_new','additionalMessage_new'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df
```

I then sort it by the date column, which is why it is important to be able to run it for every month, as I need to repeat this process and hopefully automate it in the future:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['marketPeriodStart']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df = df = df.sort_values(by='new', ascending=True)
df
```

[image: Dataframe]

As the API can only run in one month periods, I am trying to loop-through it to be able to change the "fromdate" param to every month. I can then change the "corridor" param and I would be able to  repeat the above for-loop. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to get data from 2021-01-01 to date?

Comment: Yes, I want to get whole of 2021, and 2022 to date but I think the API can only do one month at a time hence I was thinking a loop would be required.

Comment: yes you need a loop but, will the corridor parameter change in each loop?

Comment: It doesn't need too. There are only two corridor parameters so I can manually change that parameter as and when needed (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all data:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
Base_URL = "https://api.jao.eu/OWSMP/getauctions?"

headers = {
"AUTH_API_KEY": "api_key"
}

final_df=pd.DataFrame() #all data will store here.

#create dates like 2022-01-01, 2022-08-01...
year=['2021','2022']
month=list(range(1,13))
dates=[]
errors=[]
for i in year:
    for j in month:
        if i =='2022' and j in [11,12]:
            pass
        else:
            dates.append(i+ '-' + f'{j:02}' + '-01')

#dates are ready. let's request for each date and append data to final df. 
for i in dates:    
    params = {
    "horizon":"Daily",
    "corridor":"IF1-FR-GB",
    "fromdate":i
    }
    
    data = "results"
    
    
    r = requests.get(Base_URL, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
    j = r.json()
    try:
       df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
       final_df=final_df.append(df)
    except:
       errors.append(j)

#now, let's do same process for final data.
final_df=final_df.explode('results')
final_df=final_df.join(pd.json_normalize(final_df.pop('results')).add_suffix('_new'))
final_df.drop(['ftroption','identification','horizonName','periodToBeSecuredStart','periodToBeSecuredStop','bidGateOpening','bidGateClosure','isBidGateOpen','atcGateOpening','atcGateClosure','marketPeriodStop','disputeSubmissionGateOpening','disputeSubmissionGateClosure','disputeProcessGateOpening','disputeProcessGateClosure','ltResaleGateOpening','ltResaleGateClosure','maintenances','xnRule','winningParties','operationalMessage','products','lastDataUpdate','cancelled','comment_new','corridorCode_new','productIdentification_new','additionalMessage_new'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

After you get all the data, if you want to get it automatically every month, you should set it to run on the first day of every month (if you want a different day, you should change the day value in **timedelta**).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
Base_URL = "https://api.jao.eu/OWSMP/getauctions?"

headers = {
"AUTH_API_KEY": "api_key"
}


from datetime import datetime,timedelta
now=(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-01')
params = {
"horizon":"Daily",
"corridor":"IF1-FR-GB",
"fromdate":now
}

data = "results"


r = requests.get(Base_URL, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
j = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
df=df.append(df)
df=df.explode('results')
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('results')).add_suffix('_new'))
df.drop(['ftroption','identification','horizonName','periodToBeSecuredStart','periodToBeSecuredStop','bidGateOpening','bidGateClosure','isBidGateOpen','atcGateOpening','atcGateClosure','marketPeriodStop','disputeSubmissionGateOpening','disputeSubmissionGateClosure','disputeProcessGateOpening','disputeProcessGateClosure','ltResaleGateOpening','ltResaleGateClosure','maintenances','xnRule','winningParties','operationalMessage','products','lastDataUpdate','cancelled','comment_new','corridorCode_new','productIdentification_new','additionalMessage_new'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had this previously also but I am getting an error ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index, relating to (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j))

Comment: can you use `df=pd.json_normalize(j['results'])` instead of `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)`

Comment: That returns a key error. This is what happened before when I tried to normalise on results initially which I had to work around

Comment: okey, I added a 'try-except` code to the answer. this saves the json data from which you received the error to a list called **errors** from the request you received. Most likely, you are getting this error because the json data does not match each other.  compare the json added to the list called **errors** with the others, if there is a difference in the format, we may need to write a new condition.

Comment: I think you're right, it now yields a key error for results so I reckon the json data doesn't match